# Recaptcha check page returns nothing

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have a feedback webpage on my PHP-based project. The feedback page has a form with all the fields I need and i put recaptcha display there and it works just fine: everything is displayed properly and functions according to the google manuals. The form "action" is set to another page which should just check recaptcha, prevent sql injections and insert the user message to the db. Everything seems simple.

The problem however is in this second page. It just returns blank even though it shouldnt:

```
<?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "my private key";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
     //in this case the returned page is totally blank
     echo <<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="WhiteSmoke">

EOT;

    switch ($_POST["lang"]) {
    case "en":
        echo <<<EOT

<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="100" height="100" align="center" valign="middle"><h3>CAPTCHA failed ($resp->error)!</h3></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <meta HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' content='3; url=feedback_en.php'>
</body>
</html>
EOT;
        break;
    //here go other possible $_POST['lang'] values which i removed from the sample since its irrelevant
}
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
    //in this case the page returns totally blank either

    //here goes some db stuff

    //here goes sql injection check which is also skipped for this code

    //more db stuff

        switch ($_POST["lang"]) {
    case "en":
        echo <<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Thank you!</title>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' content='3; url=feedback_en.php'>
</head>

<body bgcolor="WhiteSmoke">
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="100" height="100" align="center" valign="middle"><h3>Thank you for the feedback, with your help this service will be better!</h3></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
EOT;
        break;
    //and so on...
} //end of switch
    //and we have nothing
  }
  ?>
```

As noted in the code, whatever the result of the test, the output page is blank. It only works somewhat decent if to leave recaptcha field completely empty. It returns HTML according to the idea with the text "CAPTCHA failed (incorrect-captcha-sol)!"

Comment: Blank pages on a php site usually indicate an error. Turn on debugging (display_errors/error_reporting), check your server logs, etc... And then leave those on while you're developing. In devel mode, they should never be off in the first place.

Comment: Im using my debug subdomain with all error reporting totally on (which is sometimes annoying but useful with all the warnings). Here I have no errors, no warnings, just plain blank...

Comment: then start putting in debug output in thes cript. `echo 'here I am!'` in various places and see where the script aborts. did you look at `view source` incase the html's there but incomplete so it renders as a blank page?

Comment: I've been using this trick with my other numerous issues and it helped. Will do that to the problematic page and to recaptchalib.php. And yes, i've looked into the HTML code of the generated page in the browser. Its just blank!

Comment: Allright
  `<?php
  echo "<br> 1";

  require_once('recaptchalib.php');

   echo "<br> 2";`
And there are two other outputs after "true" and "false" results. I see only first two. Didn't go into the recaptcalib.php. I wonder if i should change some parameters at my hosting php setup page.